# Find the coordinates of a path of a moving point in a triangle with 2 fixed points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, triangles

Let $A(0,1)$, $B(0,-1)$, and $C_t(x,y)$ such that $AC_t = t$ and $BC_t = t + 1$.
Another way to say it is that the triangle $A\,B\,C_t$ has one fixed (vertical) side of length $2$, one side of length $t$ and one of length $t+1$.

[image]

**Question: How to find a description of the path of $C_t$ when we make $t$ vary in $\mathbb{R}^+$?**

I'm looking for a description as $y = f(x)$, or if not possible, the addition of two (or more) curves $y=f(x)$.

---

Note:

- this comes from a triangulation problem (time difference between sound events and GPS coordinates, I will link a complete description when finished), see "Application" in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50611940/1422096).
- I've tried it by drawing lots of circles on a sheet of paper, the path of $C_t$ seems to be **a line**, but not 100% sure
- Analytically, I found something like $y = f(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} x + \frac 12$, but the computations were horrible, not elegant (there's probably much clever), and there are probably other possible paths $y = g(x)$ with a different $g$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is a branch of the hyperbola having $A$ and $B$ as foci. Because that hyperbola is the locus of points $C$ such that $|CB-CA|$ is constant.

[image]

In your case focal distance is $c=1$ while semi-major axis is $a=|CB-CA|/2=1/2$. Semi-conjugate axis is then $b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}=\sqrt3/2$ and the equation of the hyperbola is
$$
4y^2-{4\over3}x^2=1.
$$

Comment: How can we prove this again (I don't remember how it works)? Would you have the x, y coordinates of C?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Definition_of_a_hyperbola_as_locus_of_points